# How to get displayed a system variable read from external txt file with FOR /F expanded?

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I am making a query on a txt file via Windows command prompt, but the output displayed is actual content of txt file, instead of system variable.

Any idea how can I amend that?

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (Backup_Folder.txt) DO (
    echo %%H
)
```

Output is

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Electronic Arts
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Electronic Arts
```

Content of `Backup_Folder.txt` is:

```
EA,%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Electronic Arts
```

Comment: Use `CALL echo %%H`

Comment: Nice... Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use in the batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%G IN (Backup_Folder.txt) do call echo %%H
```

It is better to use `tokens=1*` instead of `tokens=1,2` in case of the folder path stored in the text file contains per chance also a comma, for example:

```
EA,%USERPROFILE%\Documents,Settings\Electronic Arts
```

The asterisk after `1` means the rest of the line after the comma(s) after first comma delimited string without further splitting up the line on commas. So with `tokens=1*` the loop variable `G` gets assigned `EA` and loop variable `H` gets assigned `%USERPROFILE%\Documents,Settings\Electronic Arts`. The usage of `tokens=1,2` results in `H` gets assigned just `%USERPROFILE%\Documents,` for that example.

The command **CALL** is necessary in this specific case to get on execution of the body of the loop after replacing `%%H` by `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Electronic Arts` in first parsing step the command line parsed a second time by Windows command interpreter to expand additionally `%USERPROFILE%`.

When the folder path read from text file is assigned to an environment variable, I recommend to use as command `set "FolderPath=%%~H"` or `call set "FolderPath=%%~H"` for getting all environment variable references in folder path already expanded before assigning the folder path to the environment variable.

The tilde character between `%%` and `H` results on a folder path like `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents & Settings\Electronic Arts"` stored in the text file that the surrounding double quotes are removed making it possible to use the environment variable for example in a command line like:

```
if exist "%FolderPath%\Game\game.exe" echo Game exists.
```

A space as well as `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` in a file/folder name without or with path require the usage of surrounding double quotes as output by Windows command interpreter on last help page on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`. In argument strings not being a file/folder name/path the additionally possible characters `|<>` require also that the entire argument string is enclosed in straight double quotes to get those redirection operators interpreted as literal characters.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`